# Schema validation warnings twilio

Tags: java, twilio

I have developed a call function with Twilio. I got the call successfully but got an error triggered which is **Schema validation warnings twilio** .

My function for call is

```
String callText;
if(!preferredStaff.equals("No")){
    // customize message of phone
    callText=userName+" さんが、 "+shopName+" の "+booking+" に予約を入れました。担当は "+preferredStaff+" を希望です ";
}else{
    callText=userName+" さんが、 "+shopName+" の "+booking+" に予約を入れました。";   
}
callText = callText.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");
callText = callText.replaceAll("<", "&lt;");
callText = callText.replaceAll(">", "&gt;");
callText = callText.replaceAll("\"", "&quot;");
callText = callText.replaceAll("'", "&#39;");
// replace whitespace
callText = callText.replace(" ", "      ");
//twiml settings
String twiml = "<Response><Say voice='woman' language='ja-jp' speed='0.5'>" + callText + "</Say>"+"</Response>";           
// response of call
String Url = "http://twimlets.com/echo?Twiml=" + URLEncoder.encode(twiml, "utf-8");
```

This trigger is for

- Misspelling of verb
- Illegal case of the verb
- Attribute unknown or misspelled
- Element of unknown nest or incorrect.

Help is needed as i am cofused about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I'm pretty sure that `speed` is not a valid attribute for the `<Say>` verb.  I couldn't find it in the docs.  Including that attribute would cause a schema validation warning.

Hope that helps.